# The method of using Regular Expression to express Date and Time: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.XXX

Tags: regex, linux

How to use Regular Expression to express Date and Time format like this: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.XXX, use the standard Regular Expression.
For example, "2018-08-01 23:58:32.425","2018-08-01 23:58:29.250","2016-11-01 19:10:34.911", I list some time & date strings.

Comment: `\d` (or if unimplemented `[0-9]`) represents a digit, `{n}` is a quantifier that specifies the previous token should be matched *n* times, `\.` must be escaped to match a literal dot, every other character (`- :`) can be written as is. That's all you should need to write a regex matching your dates. Good luck !

Comment: Can you provide an input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\d\d\d\d-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])\.(\d{3})$
```

It will match the format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fff
```

Test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/D43KtJ/1).

Comment: Thank you for your help so much，I see it.